# Using SELECT from RETURNING while UPDATE in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables T1,T2 I have to add the column id of T1 in T2 and update a value in T1.

So I am able to get the values from T2 using RETURNING,but when using values in UPDATE WHERE then not able to UPDATE the column

Example:

```
  WITH "T1S" AS (INSERT INTO "T1" VALUES()RETURNING id AS "T1id" ),
  "T2S" AS (INSERT INTO "T2"(t1_id) VALUES(
                                  (SELECT "T1id" FROM "T1S"))
                                  )RETURNING t1_id AS "T1id",t2_id AS "T2id"
                                  )
  UPDATE "T1" set value=t2_id WHERE id IN (SELECT t1_id FROM "T2S")
```

[Image of query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Lx0K.png)

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_name

Comment: It would be really helpful if you can share a sample data set and expected output. It is difficult to understand your requirements. Check this --> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: Let me explain you from starting,

Comment: I have two tables, I want that the id of one table should be get inserted into another one, so what am I doing is that INSERTING the first table, getting its value then INSERTING in another table putting value of the previous value(which was retrieved) getting the values from the table and updating the first table value(in which I want to insert id of the next table) So, T1 is the first table, T2 is the second table, In T1 I want the id of T2 and in T2 I want the id of T1.

Comment: I have kept the field of T1 as NOT NULL,then after T2 table gets INSERTED, I get it's id and update the field of T1 by giving the id of T2.

Comment: Both T1 and T2 id's are SERIAL.

Comment: The problem here is that I am INSERTING and then UPDATING the table, by this the database is not able to detect the new entry for INSERT.If I use (SELECT id FROM "T1" ORDER BY id DESC), then I am getting the id of the previous entry, not the current entry.

Comment: Please don't add additional information in  coments. **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is the logic that you want:

```
WITH T1S AS (
      INSERT INTO "T1"
          VALUES ()
          RETURNING id AS T1id
     ),
     T2S AS (
      INSERT INTO "T2" (t1_id)
          SELECT T1ID
          FROM T1S
          RETURNING *
    )
UPDATE "T1" t1
    SET value = T2S.t2_id
    FROM T2S
    WHERE t1.id = T2S.t1_id;
```

Notes:

- Using double quotes for table and column names is a bad practice.  Using them for CTEs and column aliases is an absurdity.  They just make references harder.
- The solution is that you want the join the table to the CTE in the final `UPDATE`.

Comment: When I use my same query with predefined WHERE clause Id then it is working fine, but when using it with RETUTNING and Inserting table too at that time gives error